# Sagemaker model deployment fails: /opt/ml/model fails with OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, aws-code-deploy, amazon-ecr

I am deploying a trained/customized model on Sagemaker. Container creation and training works perfectly well. I can my model's pickle files but when I run

> predictor = model.deploy(1, instance_type='ml.t2.medium',
> serializer=csv_serializer)

It throws the above error. I have changed permissions, model output paths, and changed instance types to bigger and smaller than ml.c4.2xlarge but nothing has worked. Super disappointed in Sagemaker with its poor documentation. I was following this [tutorial](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/2bd685e509753ebffdf3f716e22afd005c6eac0d/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own/container) and been blocked on this for 3 days!!!

Also, tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53595157/aws-sagemaker-deploy-fails) but my problem persists.

Docker file:

```
    FROM ubuntu:18.04

MAINTAINER Amazon AI <sage-learner@amazon.com>


ARG REGION=us-west-2

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
         wget \
         python3-pip \
         python3-setuptools \
         nginx \
         ca-certificates \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


RUN pip3 install numpy
RUN pip3 install pandas
RUN pip3 install flask
RUN pip3 install gunicorn

# RUN pip3 install python3


ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=TRUE
ENV PATH="/opt/ml:${PATH}"

# /opt/ml and all subdirectories are utilized by SageMaker, we use the /code subdirectory to store our user code.
COPY model-1 /opt/ml/

# this environment variable is used by the SageMaker PyTorch container to determine our user code directory.
ENV SAGEMAKER_SUBMIT_DIRECTORY /opt/ml/
WORKDIR /opt/ml/



# this environment variable is used by the SageMaker PyTorch container to determine our program entry point
# for training and serving.
# For more information: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-pytorch-container
ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "/opt/ml/train.py"]

# ENV SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM train
```

and this is my build_and_push.sh

```
%%sh

#!/usr/bin/env bash

# The name of our algorithm
algorithm_name=model-1-algo
cd container

chmod +x model-1/data/
chmod +x model-1/training/
chmod +x model-1/preprocessors/
chmod +x model-1/model/
chmod +x model-1/output/
chmod +x model-1/train.py
chmod +x model-1/serve
chmod +x Dockerfile

account=$(aws sts get-caller-identity --query Account --output text)

# Get the region defined in the current configuration (default to us-west-2 if none defined)
region=$(aws configure get region)
region=${region:-us-west-2}

fullname="${account}.dkr.ecr.${region}.amazonaws.com/${algorithm_name}:latest"

# If the repository doesn't exist in ECR, create it.

aws ecr describe-repositories --repository-names "${algorithm_name}" > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    aws ecr create-repository --repository-name "${algorithm_name}" > /dev/null
fi

# Get the login command from ECR and execute it directly
$(aws ecr get-login --region ${region} --no-include-email)

# REGISTRY_ID = 520713654638
# REGISTRY_ID = $(763104351884)
# Build the docker image locally with the image name and then push it to ECR with the full name.

docker build  -t ${algorithm_name} . --build-arg REGION=${region}
docker tag ${algorithm_name} ${fullname}

docker push ${fullname}
```

Comment: Forgot to add: tried this as well - desperation, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66085892/aws-batch-extract-tar-gz-file-to-opt-ml-model-fails-with-oserror-errno-30-re. officially going crazy.

Comment: Adding the docker file will help as you are using custom container and your inference script, if possible.

Comment: could you run the command `docker run -it image bash` and run the command `ls -l /` ?

Comment: What does your mode-1 dir contain? Are there any hidden files or links?  Is there a reason you COPY it into /opt/ml ? Can you COPY it to some other directory?